# Parse urls, loop file_get_html(urls) and then get element

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, foreach, simple-html-dom

I have a site which I need to parse it.

First, I have to parse all catalog's urls in the page, then I need to enter all urls then go through all the urls and parse urls on each page again, then go through all urls and get element ('.description div').

I'm using simple html dom.

But I have one problem in moment when I want to go through all urls which I parse for the first time.
I'm getting empty page

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$catalogs = file_get_html('http://optnow.ru/catalog');
$catalogLink = [];
if(!empty($catalogs)) {
    foreach( $catalogs->find('div.cat-name a') as $catalog) {
         $catalogUrl = 'http://optnow.ru/' . $catalog->href . '?page=0';
         $catalogLink[] = $catalogUrl;
         $catalogHtml = file_get_html($catalogUrl);
         $productsLink = $catalogHtml->find('.link-pv-name');
         print_r($productsLink->href);
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: `$catalogLink[0] as $catalogSingleLink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass array, not a single element in foreach:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$catalog = file_get_html('http://optnow.ru/catalog');
$catalogLink = [];
if(!empty($catalog)) {
    foreach( $catalog->find('div.cat-name a') as $catalogHref) {
         $myLink = 'http://optnow.ru/' . $catalogHref->href . '?page=0';
         $catalogLink[] = $myLink;
         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($myLink);
         echo '</pre>';
    }
    foreach ($catalogLink as $catalogSingleLink ) {
         if(!empty($catalogSingleLink)) {
             $catalogHtml = file_get_html($catalogSingleLink);
             $catalogProduct = $catalogHtml->find('.link-pv-name');
             echo $catalogProduct->href;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I print $catalogSinglLink I'll get just string of all urls like that http://optnow.ru/categories/istochniki-pitaniya?page=0http://optnow.ru/categories/avtoaksessuary?page=0http://optnow.ru/categories/selfie?page=0http://optnow.ru/categories/audio-aksessuary?

Comment: Ok, but I need to get only one url, then next in each loop. I need to make for() loop and iterate each url?

Comment: @Frunky no I mean to say that you'll get all URLs individually. The code would work as you expect. Try it

Comment: I'm really don't know why I'm getting empty result. I'll update question now, thanks